# Pointer issues with object in c++ vector

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory, vector

So I have a Node type, and Object1 type extending the node type, and a geoType type (which will later be extended into several different geometry updating types).

I am trying to make a vector of Object1, that when I call updateLoc will call the update function on the attached geoType, which updates the location vector in the node.

I set it up this way because I would like to have several different geoTypes to update the Node in different ways. I have an issue here though.

Attached is my code : https://onlinegdb.com/HJlNDlY2z

//classes.h
    #include

```
class Node;
class geoType{
public:
    geoType();
    virtual ~geoType();
    void SetNode(Node *pointer);
    void Update();
private:
    Node* node;
};

class Node{
public:
    Node();
    virtual ~Node();
    void updateGeo();
    std::vector<double> getLoc();
    std::vector<double> location;
private:
};

class Object1: public Node{
public:
    Object1();
    virtual ~Object1();
    void setGeo(geoType* a);
    void updateLoc();
private:
    geoType* geo;
};
```

//classes.cpp

```
#include "Classes.h"

geoType::geoType(){
    node = 0;
}
geoType::~geoType(){}
void geoType::SetNode(Node *pointer){node = pointer;}
void geoType::Update(){node->location[0] = node->location[0] + 1;}

Node::Node(){location = std::vector<double>(3);}
Node::~Node(){}
void Node::updateGeo(){location[0] = location[0] + 1;}
std::vector<double> Node::getLoc(){return location;}

Object1::Object1(){geo = 0;}
Object1::~Object1(){}
void Object1::setGeo(geoType* a){geo = a;}
void Object1::updateLoc(){geo->Update();}
```

//main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Object1> objs;

    Object1 a;
    geoType* aGeo = new geoType;
    a.setGeo(aGeo);

    objs.push_back(a);
    aGeo->SetNode(&objs[0]);

    //objs[0].updateLoc();
    //std::cout<<objs[0].getLoc()[0] << '\n';
    //objs[0].updateLoc();
    //std::cout<<objs[0].getLoc()[0] << '\n';

    Object1 b;
    geoType* bGeo = new geoType;
    b.setGeo(bGeo);

    objs.push_back(b);
    bGeo->SetNode(&objs[1]);

    //for(int i = 0; i<objs.size();i++){
    //    objs[i].updateLoc();
    //    std::cout<<objs[i].getLoc()[0] << '\n';
    //}

    //for(int i = 0; i<objs.size();i++){
    //    objs[i].updateLoc();
    //    std::cout<<objs[i].getLoc()[0] << '\n';
    //}

    Object1 c;
    geoType* cGeo = new geoType;
    c.setGeo(cGeo);

    objs.push_back(c);
    cGeo->SetNode(&objs[2]);

    for(int i = 0; i<objs.size();i++){
        objs[i].updateLoc();
        std::cout<<objs[i].getLoc()[0] << '\n';
    }

    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it seems to be properly updating only one of the objects in the vector. I am confused why. It is properly looping, but the output is not all ones as I expect. Also depending on the vector's size, I sometimes get a stack dump in eclipse.

Comment: `aGeo->SetNode(&objs[0]);` --  Good chance this goes up in a puff of smoke on the next `push_back`.  [Read up on what invalidates entries inside a vector](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objs.push_back(b);` might invalidate previous pointer on `obj[i]` (if reallocation happens)

Comment: Adding `objs.reserve(3);` to OPs code confirms this.